# Problem when filtering a selection with jQuery

Tags: jquery, filter

```
$("[title != '' ]").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('lkBox');
});
```

I´ve been programming some stuffs in my job and i used to filter empty title elements by the script over this text. Is it correctly? I tested in my localserver with a simple HTML page that i mounted and everthing was ok.

Comment: So you have some code, you tested it, it works, and then you thought it would be a good idea to ask the Internet whether it's correct? Why!? If I have to mention one thing you could improve, it's that you might want to add an element name to the selector as well if you only have titles on certain types of elements. Will speed the query up a little.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a test platform. If everything was OK, what's your *problem when filtering*?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi It appears to me that OP is consulting people who might know if there are possible unintended consequences of this filter. If you don't care to answer such a question, move along.   Imagine if France had considered the law of unintended consequences before the treaty of Versailles?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi I unintentionally hit enter and posted before my thought was complete, see edited comment above..

Comment: @Cos Callis, never mind that. I was just pointing out that the title is misleading: there can be no problem if everything ends up being OK, so the question itself ends up being quite vague and subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct. You are using the [`Not Equal Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between your example and jQuery documentation is that they switch the single quotes and double quotes, and they don't have spaces, so try this:

```
$('[title!=""]').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('lkBox');
});
```

Alternatively, check that the titles on the page it is not working on are **actually empty**.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a place to test (your website etc.), use online resources like [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/), there you can do simple examples and [see if it worked](http://jsfiddle.net/GdeBc/)